# Split string at double quotes and box brackets

Tags: python, split

I'm just starting on Python and I'm trying to split a string with double quotes AND box brackets.

Example:

```
10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /assets/js/lowpro.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10469
```

Wanted Outcome:

```
ip: 10.223.157.186
identity: -
username: -
time: [15/Jul/2009:15:50:35 -0700]
request: "GET /assets/js/lowpro.js HTTP/1.1"
status: 200
size: 10469
```

I would like to split them at the 'space' but it will also split the parts between the `[]` and `""`. Like this:

```
['10.223.157.186', '-', '-', '[15/Jul/2009:14:58:59', '-0700]', '"GET', '/assets/js/lowpro.js', 'HTTP/1.1"', '200', '10469']
```

I have seen many possible solutions like:

- `shlex` (my python doesn't import it)
- `data = line.strip().split('\"')`

but that gives a strange output too
and to be honest I don't really understand the regex, also I don't know if I can import is as the shlex.

Comment: If you don't have `shlex`, would you mind telling us what version of Python you are running (should be the first thing Python outputs at the interactive prompt)?

Comment: This is probably a good opportunity to learn a little bit about regex...

Comment: I just realized that your question says that you want to handle the quotes, but your example doesn't actually do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go against the "regex grain" and say to use a *parser*; a parser is a level of complexity above regular expressions and usually employs regular expressions to define parts of its grammar. My library of choice is [`pyparsing`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing). You'd use it like this:

```
>>> s = '10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /assets/js/lowpro.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10469'
>>> from pyparsing import ZeroOrMore, Regex
>>> parser = ZeroOrMore(Regex(r'\[[^]]*\]') | Regex(r'"[^"]*"') | Regex(r'[^ ]+'))
>>> for i in parser.parseString(s): print i
...
10.223.157.186
-
-
[15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700]
"GET /assets/js/lowpro.js HTTP/1.1"
200
10469
```

Note that the order of the tokens (those `Regex` object things) is important. By putting the square bracket and double quoted tokens first, they get precedence. It doesn't work right if you put the last one first. One nice property about doing it this way is that it's easier to extend to be more complicated than a regular expression (which only supports regular language operations, unless you do a bunch of insane look-around stuff). For example, a parser can help you break apart the pieces inside those brackets or quotes if you ever decide you want to, and with a little work, you could change the parser to allow for nested brackets or quotes. (The latter is something that real regular expressions *cannot do*. You might be able to get a regular expression with look-around extensions to do it, but it's not worth it in my opinion. Parsers are much more powerful and, in my experience, simpler to understand and use.)

Note that the parser doesn't just return a list or iterable. It returns its own special object:

```
>>> parser.parseString(s)
(['10.223.157.186', '-', '-', '[15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700]', '"GET /assets/js/lowpro.js HTTP/1.1"', '200', '10469'], {})
>>> type(parser.parseString(s))
<class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
```

I think I should also explain my regular expressions.

- `\[[^]]*\]`: this just matches a pair of square brackets, optionally with something inbetween them. `\[` says it needs to start with a square bracket. `[^]]` is a *character class* (just a set of characters in a regular expression); the outer brackets make it a character class. The `^` tells it "anything other that what's in the character list," and the inner `]` is just the character list. So that part is just "anything other than `]`". The `*` means "zero or more of the previous thing," so it means "zero or more characters other than `]`". Last is the `\]`, which just means that it needs to end with a `]`. The initial `[` and final `]` must be escaped with the `\` since they are normally used to indicate a character class.
- `"[^"]*"`: This is pretty much the same as the last one. `"` says it must start with a double quote. `[^"]` is the same kind of character class as before; it means "anything other than a double quote". The `*` still means "zero or more". The final `"` just means it must end with a quote. So this is just "zero or more characters surrounded by double quotes".
- `[^ ]+`: `[^ ]` is yet another of the same kind of character class. It just means "any character other than a space," since the character list is a space. The `+` means "one or more of the previous thing" (similar to the `*`, except that it requires at least one). So this is "one or more non-space characters".

The `|` operator between the `Regex` objects is just "or"-ing the different tokens together, so that the parser spits out a token as soon as it can match one of these three possible tokens.

Comment: @user3523150 No problem. If one of our answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
line = """10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /assets/js/lowpro.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10469\n"""

import re

log_line = re.compile('(?P<ip>[^ ]*) (?P<identity>[^ ]*) (?P<username>[^ ]*) \\[(?P<time>[^\\]]*)\\] "(?P<request>[^"]*)" (?P<status>[^ ]*) (?P<size>[^ ]*)$')

for key, value in log_line.match(line).groupdict().iteritems():
    print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
```

You can also use a parser, as suggested by @jpmc26.